# Reddit get ads report API

Tags: java, rest, reddit, redditkit, reddit-access-token

I'm trying to get the report for an account from Reddit using their ads API.

I did the authentication process according to: https://ads-api.reddit.com/docs/#section/Authentication

When I invoked the report API, https://ads-api.reddit.com/api/v2.0/accounts/t2_3nkpasz3/reports?start_date=2019-07-16&end_date=2019-07-22&group_by=date, I got the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "This account is not allowed to use the API."
  }
}
```

The reporting API documents can be found in https://ads-api.reddit.com/docs/#tag/Reporting

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: i cannot find it , can you tell?

Comment: Please try these steps:
https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/9li6le/reddit_api_how_do_i_authenticate_trying_to_do/

Comment: Already did the same but still getting:{"error": {"message": "This account is not allowed to use the API."}}

Comment: To use the Ads API do i need to register to "Reddit API Terms of Use"at https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSezNdDNK1-P8mspSbmtC2r86Ee9ZRbC66u929cG2GX0T9UMyw/viewform  ?
if yes , how much time will take Reddit to approve my registration and start using the API ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have reached out to the Reddit sales rep, who had white-listed my Reddit account. here both the user account and the ads accounts need to be whitelisted